# httpclient.execute(httpPost) error

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

In my android application I try to send a json object to a distant server, when I run it I get an error in httpclient.execute(httpPost)
This is a part of my code.

```
public static String GET(String url , JSONObject js){ 

    try {
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);         

        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic **********");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(js.toString()));

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();            
        httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.i("Console", "Error");
    }
```

Any help please.

Comment: What kind of error? Post your stack-trace... maybe add `e.printStackTrace()`  in the `catch` clause

Comment: I bet the error is something like "NetworkOnMainThreadException" :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Problem is, that you try to run your Network Request from your Main Thread.

I would discourage you to use the Apache HTTP Client at all.

It became deprecated for Marshmallow, see [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html)

Maybe try [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). It offers you the possibility to run a request asynchronously.